# How to receive power off events in a Symbian console application?

Tags: c++, mobile, symbian, s60

I am looking for a working code example for Symbian S60 5th edition in which a console application can receive power off events (i.e. detect phone switch off). I know how to do this from UI application [`AppUI`, `HandleSystemEventL(const TWsEvent& aEvent)`, etc], but Windows Server does not seem to send events if simple console application is listening to these events.

So, I have tried to connect to WS, call `EventReady(&iStatus)`, but `RunL` is never called, and the application never receives `EApaSystemEventShutdown`.

Can anyone here provide working code for this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CSaveNotifier` (`savenotf.h`, `powermgrcli.lib`) to receive powerdown notifications. Sorry, don't have a code snippet available at the moment.

Comment: No, it does not work. I have followed instructions on how to use CSaveNotifier (what is written in "Symbian OS Internals"), but the function SaveL() from MSaveObserver never gets called. The mechanism may apply to UI-based applications only.